# Title link points to portal, not to list

Tags: list, wss-3.0, url, wss

I have an unusual problem. One of my SharePoint lists suddenly displays the title link differently, and we are not sure why.  Let's say my SharePoint portal (WSS 3.0) is http://www.futility.com. My site, FOO, has a url of /tools/foo. So, the site url would be:

http://www.futility.com/tools/foo

My list is called BAR. So, the title link for the first item should be:

http://www.futility.com/tools/foo/Lists/bar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

Instead, the title link is:

http://www.futility.com/?ID=1

If you click the title, it takes you to the home page for the portal. The Source tag is correctly generated also. This is the same for all views, and both the Title link and the Title link with menu. I created a List Template with content, and created a new list both on the same site and on a different site on my staging server, same behavior: The portal URL + /?ID=1.

What is causing this?

Comment: Were the default Add, Edit, View forms modified for this list in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes, There is a custom Web Part in the Dispform.aspx page. However, the List Web Part (The web part that shows all the fields) is NOT there, it should be minimized and hidden. Could this be the problem? And it is not in the Closed Web Part Gallery. How do I get this web part back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2007 has a known issue where if you delete the default ListViewWebPart from one of the default pages associated with a list that it has the effect of breaking several aspects of the list.  Usually the first area where this noticed is the 'New' functionality on the list menu stops working properly but the effect you are seeing is also possible.

I had not looked into this particular issue for some time, but it appears that [Microsoft now has a possible solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000858) that looks fairly easy to implement and doesn't require you to rebuild the list.

Comment: Thank you, Dave! The fix from Microsoft worked. +1000 Internets for you today.